# Retrieving service account info from IIS logs

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-logs

I have a WCF service and I want to check under which service account was a call made to the service two days ago. Can I find that information in IIS logs?

To clarify - another application made a call to my WCF Service and I need to check if that application runs under a service account or is it anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check cs-username field in IIS logs. For anonymous it is -